# Fastest way to search for users logged into multiple computers within an OU of AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Im trying to create a powershell script where you enter a username and it will parse all machines in a specific ou and see if they are logged into multiple machines.

I am not quite sure whether WMI, CIM or query will provide me with the fastest query to see if a user will be logged into additional machines that could prevent account lockout in AD.

What is the best way to enter an a username, then have it scan a specific OU and output the results to a .csv file?

Thanks

Comment: CIM is faster than WMI, so that is an easy decision. [*grin*] as for the rest ... what have you tried? this is not a code-writing service ... it's a help-with-my-code site.

Comment: Ive been playing around with the script that is available [link] (http://blog.ratavaara.com/2015/01/15/find-computers-that-a-specific-user-is-logged-on-to/) however, I do not know how to use this script to search a specific ou in AD, or how to speed up the process so that it takes less then 5 minutes to complete.  I need to figure out how to modify this script to query AD for the imputed username against a specific ou

Comment: have you tried using the AD computer cmdlet to get the info? i _think_ it has a `-SearchBase` parameter to limit your search to the OU listed. once you have that, you can see if it has "current logged in user" info. ///// i do NOT have access to the AD stuff, so this is just from reading other posts.

Comment: to check if/who is logged into a computer, I use $loggedon += Get-WMIObject -computername $computer -query "Select name,username from Win32_computersystem" -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object Name,UserName | ? {$_.Username -ne $null}

Comment: If you have access to the DC then checking specific logon event logs (eventID 4624) would probably be a bit faster. You could then filter it down to the last few days etc.

Comment: I would use `Get-ADComputer -Searchbase` to get the computers. Then I would create a scriptblock with a query that you use to discover logged on users like `$scriptblock = {quser}`. I would then use that scriptblock with `Invoke-Command -Computername $computerlist -scriptblock $scriptblock -asjob`.

Comment: So i got it to work using gwmi win32_process -computer $Computer -Filter "Name = 'explorer.exe'" however this will go to every computer and scan the explorer process which is way to invasive.  how could i query it from the DC and leave the computers as they are.  Can you tell me a method to try using event ids in the even logs to see if i can compare it?

Answer (score 0):

If in your AD environment you have a share on a server where all user home directories are stored, this may be a solution.

It connects to the server and gets a list of user connections with that home directories share.
Using that list, it looks for connections made by the given user and tests if the computer the connection was made from is in the given OU.

```
$ouDN          = 'THE DISTINGHUISHED NAME OF THE OU'
$homeDirServer = 'THE NAME OF THE SERVER WHERE THE USER HOME DIRECTORIES ARE KEPT'
$homeDirShare  = 'THE NAME OF THE SHARED ROOT FOLDER OF THE USERS HOME DIRECTORIES'
$userName      = 'SAMACCOUNTNAME OF THE USER TO SEARCH FOR'
$outputFile    = 'THE PATH AND FILENAME OF THE EXPORTED CSV FILE'

# first get a list of computernames in the given OU
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $ouDN | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

# next, get user connections on the homedir share and loop through them
Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_ServerConnection -ComputerName $homeDirServer |
# or use WMI:
# Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ServerConnection -ComputerName $homeDirServer | 

    Where-Object { $_.ShareName -eq $homeDirShare -and $_.UserName -eq $userName } | 
    # if you want a list of all user connections, use this instead:
    # Where-Object { $_.ShareName -eq $homeDirShare -and (!$($_.UserName).EndsWith("$")) } | 

    ForEach-Object {
        # get the computername from the IP Address you usually get in '$_.ComputerName'
        $computerName = (([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($_.ComputerName).HostName) -split "\.", 2)[0]
        # is this a computer in the given OU?
        if ($computers -contains $computerName) {
            # emit an object
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                'DisplayName'  = Get-ADUser -Identity $_.UserName -Properties DisplayName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName
                'AccountName'  = $_.UserName
                'ComputerName' = $computerName
       }
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path $outputFile -NoTypeInformation
```